# "List of listings" listed twice in header

Tags: header-footer

The header in my document displays: Chapters and sections below.
It also displays other "sections" like "List of listings" etc.

Problem is: The "List of listings" is displayed twice, which is ugly to look at. How can I make it display in the second line (where sections are displayed) of the header only?

[image]

[image]

Here is my (striped down) code:

```
\documentclass[
   final,
   12pt,
   a4paper,
   oneside
]{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}% to alighn the TOC numbers on the right
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}

%%# IN NEW BEGIN
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[headheight=30pt,
            a4paper,
            left=42mm,
            right=29mm,
            top=32mm,
            bottom=38mm
]{geometry}  % or %\setlength{\headheight}{30pt}
%% IN NEW END

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    %\pagestyle{fancy}
    %\pagestyle{fancyplain}
    %\fancyhead{}
    %\fancyfoot{}
    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\small\nouppercase\leftmark\\\small\nouppercase\rightmark}
    \fancyfoot[L]{\rule{2cm}{1cm}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[C]{}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
        \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
        \fancyhead[R]{\small\nouppercase\leftmark\\\small\nouppercase\rightmark}
        \fancyfoot[L]{\rule{2cm}{1cm}}
        \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
        \fancyfoot[C]{}
        \renewcommand{\headrule}{{%
        \hrule height 1.9pt width\headwidth
        \vspace{1.6pt}%
        \hrule height 0.9pt width\headwidth
    }}}
    \renewcommand{\headrule}{{%
        \hrule height 1.9pt width\headwidth
        \vspace{1.6pt}%
        \hrule height 0.9pt width\headwidth
    }}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}

%%# IN NEW BEGIN
\pagestyle{fancy}
%%# IN NEW END

\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}

%% OUT NEW BEGIN
%\fancyfoot[RO, LE] {\small\thepage}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\fancyfoot[R] {\thepage}
%% OUT NEW END

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code listing}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Listings}
\rhead{\small{List of Listings}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Listings}
\lstlistoflistings

\mainmatter

%% IN NEW BEGIN
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~#1}}
%% IN NEW END

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\onehalfspacing

%% OUT NEW BEGIN
%\fancyhead{}
%\pagestyle{plain}
%\lhead{}
%\rhead{\small\nouppercase\leftmark\\\small\nouppercase\rightmark}
%\fancyfoot[R] {\thepage}
%% OUT NEW END

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}

\chapter{Some Chapter}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\section{Some section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can add the images directly using the `img` button or `CTRL-G` instead of linking them

Comment: The answer provided by esdd already solves that problem [header and footer jumping around with \fancyhead](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224724)

Answer (score 3):

You have to patch `\tableofcontents` (and similarly `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`) because it issues `\markboth{\contentsname}{\contentsname}`. So this sets also `\rightmark` and the consequence is what you found out.

I also recommend to load `tocloft` with the `titles` option, so it won't override the definitions for those commands.

The patch consists in doing

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}
  {\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
  {\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

As an aside note that issuing `\pagenumbering` is redundant after `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`. Are you really sure you want to set `\parindent` to zero and `\parskip` to 12pt, also considering that you use `\onehalfspacing`? Please, don't do it.

```
\documentclass[
   final,
   12pt,
   a4paper,
   oneside
]{book}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}% to alighn the TOC numbers on the right
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%%# IN NEW BEGIN
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[headheight=30pt,
            a4paper,
            left=42mm,
            right=29mm,
            top=32mm,
            bottom=38mm
]{geometry}  % or %\setlength{\headheight}{30pt}
%% IN NEW END

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    %\pagestyle{fancy}
    %\pagestyle{fancyplain}
    %\fancyhead{}
    %\fancyfoot{}
    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\small\nouppercase\leftmark\\\small\nouppercase\rightmark}
    \fancyfoot[L]{\rule{2cm}{1cm}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[C]{}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
        \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
        \fancyhead[R]{\small\nouppercase\leftmark\\\small\nouppercase\rightmark}
        \fancyfoot[L]{\rule{2cm}{1cm}}
        \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
        \fancyfoot[C]{}
        \renewcommand{\headrule}{{%
        \hrule height 1.9pt width\headwidth
        \vspace{1.6pt}%
        \hrule height 0.9pt width\headwidth
    }}}
    \renewcommand{\headrule}{{%
        \hrule height 1.9pt width\headwidth
        \vspace{1.6pt}%
        \hrule height 0.9pt width\headwidth
    }}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}
  {\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
  {\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{}}
  {}{\ddt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}

%%# IN NEW BEGIN
\pagestyle{fancy}
%%# IN NEW END

\frontmatter

%% OUT NEW BEGIN
%\fancyfoot[RO, LE] {\small\thepage}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\fancyfoot[R] {\thepage}
%% OUT NEW END

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code listing}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Listings}
\rhead{\small{List of Listings}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Listings}
\lstlistoflistings

\mainmatter

%% IN NEW BEGIN
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~#1}}
%% IN NEW END

\onehalfspacing

%% OUT NEW BEGIN
%\fancyhead{}
%\pagestyle{plain}
%\lhead{}
%\rhead{\small\nouppercase\leftmark\\\small\nouppercase\rightmark}
%\fancyfoot[R] {\thepage}
%% OUT NEW END

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}

\chapter{Some Chapter}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\section{Some section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.


\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the title on the lower line, change the patch into

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}
  {\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
  {\@mkboth{\mbox{}}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you. But it it still displays in the first line. How can I make it display in the second line (where sections are displayed) of the header only?

Comment: @latenite Use `\@mkboth{}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}` instead of `\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{}`

Comment: That gives me:! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.87 \mainmatter
                
?

Comment: @latenite Sorry, I'll add the proper fix.

Comment: Actually there is something wrong. Somehow the name of the chapter is no longer displayed on the third page. Instead "List of listings" is displayed.

Comment: @latenite Of course: if you never set the `\rightmark` it doesn't change.

Comment: Oh sure. Somehow I commented: \rhead{\small\nouppercase\leftmark\\\small\nouppercase\rightmark} Thank you.